# problemas con transition

Tags: html, css, style

```css
html {
    font-family: 'Loto', sans-serif;
    color: #000;
    font-size: 20px;
}

body {
    background-color: #3BC29D;
    margin: 0;
}

header {
    background-color: #0a5b44;
    padding: 2rem;
    justify-content: center;
}

#title {
    text-align: center;
}

.barra_navegacion {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    background-color: #02966D;
}

section div img {
    margin: 1rem;
    width: 400px;
    box-shadow: 0 0.1rem 0.4rem rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    border: 6px solid #074634;
    background-color: #074634;
    border-radius: 0.25rem;
    color: #000; 
}

a:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 0.1rem 0.4rem rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    transition: box-shadow 5s ease;
    background-color: #0a5b44;
    transition: background-color 5s ease;
    border: 6px solid #0a5b44;
    transition: border 5s ease;


}

.lista_imagen {
    display: flex;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lato:ital,wght@0,400;0,700;1,300&family=Montserrat:wght@400;700&family=Roboto&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Energias Limpias</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <h1 id="title">Energias Limpias</h1>
    </header>
    <div class="barra_navegacion">
        <div>
            <h2>
                <a href="html/energias.html">Energias</a>
            </h2>
        </div>
        <div>
            <h2>
                <a href="html/suscripcion.html">Suscripcion</a>
            </h2>
        </div>
        <div>
            <h2>
                <a href="#contacto">Contacto</a>
            </h2>
        </div>
    </div>
    <section class="container">
        <div class="lista_imagen">
            <div>
                <img src="images/las-energias-limpias.png" alt="">
            </div>
            <div>
                <ul>
                    <li>asjdkajs ajklsdjaksjd kasjdkaj kjdklasj klajdakdjklj</li>
                    <li>jsajdlksjdkj kalsjdkl asjdklajdk asjdklasj alskdjaksjdaslk</li>
                    <li>asjdlkasjdaskldjas ajskldjaksdjaskldja jaskdjaklsdjaklsdjjd klaj</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Asperiores debitis ab quisquam! Vero nisi est minus sed amet similique, maxime, animi et, voluptatibus doloremque ratione magnam excepturi dolor corporis voluptatem.</p>
    </section>
    <footer>
        <div id="contacto">
            <p>Contactenos:</p>
            <p>Telefono: </p>
            <p>Email: energiaslimpias@gmail.com</p>
        </div>
        <p>Copyright® 2022</p>
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Tengo un problema al querer aplicarle 3 transiciones a todas mis etiquetas de tipo 'a'.
Quiero que cuando yo pase el cursor por arriba de los 'a' ejecute las 3 transiciones a la vez pero eso no pasa, me ejecuta unicamente la que se encuentra mas abajo en el codigo. Pueden ejecutar el codigo para ver que cuando se posa el cursor en en boton de la etiqueta 'a' solo funciona el del border, que es el que se encuentra mas abajo en el codigo. (Me pide mas detalle y la verdad no se que poner, tengo que ganar espacio, disculpen)

Comment: Ahi puse para que lo puedan ejecutar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

si deseas usar dos transiciones debes hacerlo en la misma linea y separandolas por ","... de esta manera:
transition: background-color 5s ease, border 5s ease;

existen otras propiedades que se rigen por este concepto ejm: box-shadow;